# Infinite sum with given precision

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this infinite sum with a given precision problem.
You can see the description in the picture below

Here's what I tried so far:

```
import math
def infin_sum(x, eps):
    sum = float(0)
    prev = ((-1)*(x**2))/2
    i = 2
    while True:
        current = prev + ((-1)**i) * (x**(2*i)) / math.factorial(2*i) 
        if(abs(current - prev) <= eps):
            print(current)
            return current
        prev = current
        i+=1
```

For the given sample input (0.2 for x and 0.00001 precision) my sum is 6.65777777777778e-05 and according to their tests it doesn't come close enough to the correct answer

Comment: A more stable way to compute it would be to sort by abs magnitude, then sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use math.isclose() instead of abs() to check your convergence (given that it's how the result will be checked).  given that each iteration adds or subtract a specific term, the delta between previous and next (Si-1 vs Si) will be equal to the last term added (so you don't need to track a previous value).

That infinite series is *almost* the one for cosine (it would be if i started at zero) so you can test your result against `math.cos(x)-1`. Also, I find it strange that the check for expected result is fixed within a precision 0.0001 but the sample input specifies a precision of 0.00001 (I guess more precise will be within 0.0001 but then, the validation is not really checking that the output is correct given the input?)

```
from math import isclose
def cosMinus1(x,precision=0.00001):
    result      = 0
    numerator   = 1
    denominator = 1
    even        = 0
    while not isclose(numerator/denominator,0,abs_tol=precision): # reach precision
        numerator   *= -x*x                     # +/- for even powers of x
        even        += 2
        denominator *= even * (even-1)          # factorial of even numbers
        result      += numerator / denominator  # sum of terms            
    return result

print(cosMinus1(0.2))
# -0.019933422222222226

import math
expected = math.cos(0.2)-1

print(expected, math.isclose(expected,cosMinus1(0.2),abs_tol=0.0001))
# -0.019933422158758374 True
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not summing the elements.

Recomputing everything from scratch is very wasteful and precision of `float`s is limited.

You can user Horner's method to refine the sum:

```
 import math                                    

 def infin_sum(x, eps):                                   
     total = float(0)                                     
     e = 1                                                
     total = 0                                            
     i = 1                                                
     while abs(e) >= eps:                                 
         diff = (-1) * (x ** 2) / (2 * i) / (2 * i - 1)   
                                                          
         e *= diff                                        
         total += e                                       
         i += 1                                           
                                                          
     return total                                                                       
                                                   
                                                   
 if __name__ == "__main__":                        
     x = infin_sum(0.2, 0.00001)                   
     print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not a good idea to shadow `sum`, you had the right idea in calling it `current`, but you didn't initialise `current` to `float(0)`, and forgot to sum it. This is your code with those problems fixed:

```py
def infin_sum(x, eps):
    current = float(0)
    prev = ((-1) * (x ** 2)) / 2
    i = 2
    while True:
        current = current + (((-1) ** i) * (x ** (2 * i))) / math.factorial(2 * i)
        if (abs(current - prev) <= eps):
            print(current)
            return current
        prev = current
        i += 1
```

As a more general comment, printing inside a function like this is probably not the best idea - it makes the reusability of the function limited - you'd want to capture the return value and print it outside the function, ideally.

Comment: There's a mistake I think we both did here. Sum starts from i = 1 and in my code, prev is basically the first element of the sum. So I think we need to add a case where we do current = prev + (equation). I added that to my code but still doesn't work :/

Answer (score -1):

Dont forget to add the result and not replace it:

```py
prev += current
```

instead of

```py
prev = current
```